# User experience when "Add to Slack" permission is denied

Tags: slack-api

**UPDATE:** Slack replied to my support request, saying they're aware of the problem and plan to address, but they can't say when. I'm still interested in workarounds.

---

**TL;DR: If a user isn't allowed to add my app** to their Slack team, why aren't they shown the "Request" button (to request permission to add the app), and what can I do as a workaround?

---

Say someone clicks the "Add to Slack" button in my app, but they are not an owner of their Slack team, and the owners don't allow users to install apps (they have set it to "Only pre-approved apps can be installed by team members"). The user sees this:
[image: Slack screen: Not authorized to install app]

The natural thing for them to do is click "message one of your admins". This shows them a list of team members, including admins. They could click on one of the admins, then click "Message", and compose a nice message explaining why they'd like to be able to install the app.

That's quite a bit of work, and it should be completely unnecessary. Slack has a built-in, one-click feature to request permission from team admins to install an app. It makes it easier for the admin to give permission, too. Unfortunately, the button to do this is completely hidden. It's on the page for my app at `[teamname].slack.com/apps/[appID]`:

[image: App page on appname.slack.com]

That big green button is exactly what my user needs at this point. But they have no way to find it, or to know that it exists!

If the user happens to click "Return to [app name]" instead of "message one of your admins", my app could redirect them to that page. But they have no way of knowing that.

I could put a message next to the "Add to Slack" button on my app, saying that IF it doesn't work, they should click the "Return to App" button. But that's a terrible user experience.

It would be great if Slack fixed this, and I'm going to try to convince them, but I think this problem has existed for quite a while, so I'm not sure how likely they are to change it.

Meanwhile, is there anything I can do to make this easier for the user? Is there any way I can change what they see on the "I'm sorry, you're not authorized" screen? Or a way to detect in advance that the team doesn't allow app installs? Or make Slack just skip this screen and go back to my app with an "access_denied" error so my app can do the right thing?

Comment: This sounds more like a question you need to ask the Slack team. Try  feedback@slack.com.

Comment: I actually filed a ticket at https://slack.com/help/requests/new and they replied very quickly; see edit at the top of the question.